# Lubuntu 18.04 LTS boot loop?

Tags: boot, lubuntu, 18.04

a few days ago, the update engine on my Lubuntu 17.10 laptop, tipped me about 18.04.
the laptop is a Acer Aspire One, and after downloading the ISO file, i restarted the laptop and opted for the life cd session in the menu.
after selecting it, it boots up from the CD (Lubuntu load screen is showed).
but after loading, the licht of the Wlan module came on (this is normal, and in 17.10, the login screen comes up shortly after that), but then goes of again and the whole boot process starts over again witout the boot menu and language list that normaly show up.
and this proces goes on and on.

is there a way to bypass this loop and to get 18.04 running?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Today i got 18.04 working fine.
after reading that some versions had a bug in their programming wich eliminates the live function of the cd, i redownloaded the ISO file from the canonical's own server. (Lubuntu.me)
this time, everything (incluis live session) went as it should be.

although i still don't know how; the fault may be in the previous ISO file i downloaded a few days ago from the website, or the burning proces on the CD after that.